# Migration to material-ui v4, I get warning for Modal component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Since upgrade `material-ui` to `v4`, I got some warnings with Modal component.

E.g

[Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Modal)`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRNa.png)

[Function components cannot be given refs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDUdM.png)

This is Modal code (warning [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRNa.png)):

```
import React from 'react';
import Proptypes from 'prop-types';
...

class DetailDialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes, open, onClose } = this.props;

    return (
      <Dialog
        open={open}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}

DetailDialog.propTypes = {
  open: Proptypes.bool,
  onClose: Proptypes.func,
};

export default DetailDialog;
```

This is Modal code (warning [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDUdM.png)):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...

class SelectCatDialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { open, list, onClose } = this.props;

    return (
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={onClose}
      >
        ...
      </Dialog>
    )
  }
}

SelectCatDialog.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool,
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
}

SelectCatDialog.defaultProps = {
  list: [],
}

export default SelectCatDialog;
```

This is call Modal page code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DetailDialog from './components/DetailDialog';
import SelectProcDialog from './components/SelectProcDialog';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
        <DetailDialog
          open={this.state.detailDialog}
          entity={this.state.currentDetail}
          onClose={this.handleDetailClose.bind(this)}
        />

        <SelectProcDialog
          open={this.state.catalogDialog}
          list={this.props.catalog}
          onOk={(value) => this.handleSelectCatalogOk(value)}
          onClose={() => this.setState({ catalogDialog: false })}
        />
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default Index;
```

What happened? Working fine in v3 version. Can someone answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since V4, Dialog and Modal children must be able to hold a ref. 
The following can hold a ref:

> - Any Material-UI component
> - class components i.e. React.Component or React.PureComponent
> - DOM (or host) components e.g. div or button
> - React.forwardRef components
> - React.lazy components
> - React.memo components

The error declares that you provide function component as a child to modal. 
To fix the error, change the function component to something that can hold a ref (e.g class component).

Comment: You are right. This is reason```function Transition(props) {
  return <Slide direction="up" {...props} />;
}```,In material-ui v3, This is a generic way of code.

Answer (score 5):

I just faced the exact same issue after migrating from Material-UI v3 to v4.

I totally agree with the accepted answer, nevertheless, I post here another approach, in the case someone would rather keep using a functional component (as I did).

**Functional components can't hold a `ref` as is.**

So the way of providing a `ref` to a child component is actually **to forward it.**

The React documentation has a well explained [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) about this, and this [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/2120#issuecomment-589207766) on the ReactJS Github details it a bit more.

So basically, what could be done here is :

```js
const Transition = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Slide direction="up" {...props} ref={ref} />
));
```

to be able to forward the ref through the `Transition` component, down to the `Slide` component.

### Typescript way

⚠️ Be aware that the previous code will throw a TS2322 error if used in a Typescript project.

This error is described and solved in this Material-UI Github [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17542#issuecomment-663845119).

So, in a Typescript project, the best way (imho) to use a functional component as `Transition` component for a Material-UI v4 `Dialog` component, is the following :

```js
import { SlideProps } from '@material-ui/core/Slide';

const Transition = React.forwardRef<unknown, SlideProps>((props, ref) => (
    <Slide direction="up" {...props} ref={ref} />
));
```

And the code above fixes both errors :

- `Failed prop type: Invalid prop children supplied to ForwardRef(Modal).`
- `[TypeScript] Error: TransitionComponent type not assignable to 'ForwardRefExoticComponent'`

Comment: How does one then "forward" the `ref` to the component? Using your above example of the new transition